# MySql select specific count of rows with start and condition

Tags: mysql, select, range, conditional-statements

I want to select a specific count of rows from MySql from an specific startpoint, with a condition. The startpoint should be a variable.
My problem is that I dont have the row where to start.

In Words:
"Start after the first 5 rows where "status" is equals 1 and give me from there the next 5 rows whith "status" equals 1".

Example Data:

```
-----------------------
| id | title | status |
-----------------------
| 1  | Test  |    1   |
| 2  | Test  |    0   |
| 3  | Test  |    1   |
| 4  | Test  |    0   |
| 5  | Test  |    1   |
| 6  | Test  |    1   |
| 7  | Test  |    0   |
| 8  | Test  |    1   |
| 9  | Test  |    1   |
| 10 | Test  |    1   |
| 11 | Test  |    1   |
| 12 | Test  |    1   |
| 13 | Test  |    0   |
| 14 | Test  |    1   |
| 15 | Test  |    0   |
```

**First Case**

I want five rows with status equals 1, started at the beginning.
(The start variable is 0).

Expected Data:

```
-----------------------
| id | title | status |
-----------------------
| 1  | Test  |    1   |
| 3  | Test  |    1   |
| 5  | Test  |    1   |
| 6  | Test  |    1   |
| 8  | Test  |    1   |
```

**Second Case**

Now I need the next 5 rows where status is equals 1.
(The start variable is 5).

Expected Data:

```
-----------------------
| id | title | status |
-----------------------
| 9  | Test  |    1   |
| 10 | Test  |    1   |
| 11 | Test  |    1   |
| 12 | Test  |    1   |
| 14 | Test  |    1   |
```

How can i achieve this?

Comment: Please add example data and expected output

Comment: can you please rephrase this *And I dont want to start with the 20. row, I need to start with the 20. row where status is equals 1*

Comment: The problem is that I dont now the specific row, where to start. When I have given as start the number 20, I want to start after 20 rows where "status" was equals 1. Instead if row 20.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the LIMIT clause. The first parameter is the index in the complete result set from where you want to start receiving results. The second parameter is the number of results you want. So to get the first 5 results:

```
SELECT * FROM my_table WHERE status = 1 ORDER BY id LIMIT 0,5
```

To get the next 5:

```
SELECT * FROM my_table WHERE status = 1 ORDER BY id LIMIT 5,5
```

And so on. Also see here: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/select.html